# Assign alias to a table in subquery MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have two tables:

1. the `exam` table which contains the score performed by students
2. and the student table

Both are joined this way: student.id=exam.student_id.

I am trying to get the firt five students who have the highest score calculated by the average of their score over 5 days using the query below:

```
SELECT 
    student.id as std_id, 
    student.name, 
    (SELECT AVG(score) FROM exam WHERE exam.student_id=std_id ORDER BY exam.timestamp DESC LIMIT 5) AS score 

FROM student 
ORDER BY score 
DESC LIMIT 5
```

I am having the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'std_id' in 'where clause'
```

I also tried it by replacing std_id by student.id but still no luck.

Any idea how to solve this issue? Great thanks

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Sorry I made a mistake in my logic. 
As said earlier on, the average is calculated for

> only the last 5 scores recorded

.
Updated query:

```
SELECT 
    student.id as std_id, 
    student.name, 
    (SELECT AVG(score) FROM (SELECT score FROM exam WHERE exam.student_id=student.id ORDER BY exam.timestamp DESC LIMIT 5) AS score) AS score 
FROM student 
ORDER BY score 
DESC LIMIT 5
```

The place which is giving the error is where I set exam.student_id=student.id

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your table definitions and a bit of example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `std_id` with `student.id` - the alias doesn't exist yet during the subquery compilation since the outer query cannot be compiled until the subquery is considered valid (and its output known).

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried this but receive the error message #1054 - Unknown column 'student.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: You guys are right and sorry I made a mistake in my logic. I just updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it should work to me (at least once the mod suggested by Niels Keurentjes has been done).

You could possibly use a generated sequence though rather than a correlated sub select. Something like thi:-

```
SELECT 
    student.id, 
    student.name, 
    AVG(Sub3.score)
FROM student
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT Sub1.student_id, Sub1.score, @aSeq := IF(@PrevStudent = student_id, @aSeq + 1, 0) AS Sequence, @PrevStudent := student_id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM exam ORDER BY student_id, timestamp DESC) Sub1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @PrevStudent := 0, @aSeq := 0) Sub2
) Sub3
ON student.id = Sub3.student_id
WHERE (Sub3.Sequence IS NULL OR Sub3.Sequence < 5)
GROUP BY student.id, student.name
```

Comment: You guys are right and sorry I made a mistake in my logic. I just updated my question. Thanks